# Using Strip Tags and check for empty fields PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

So i have a form here, and I want on the to do some php so that if the field is empty, it will say once you submit the form after it loads to the post page, that sorry you entered no date. I also want to add strip tags, however I am unsure how, if they go on the posting_wall or if they go in the form.php? I want to use strip all tags.

I believe the empty validation was if(!empty(($date)) { echo "sorry you did not enter a date"; } but i could not get it to work.

Thank you in advance if you can help me with this. I will post the form.php and the posting wall below.

Form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/header.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 150 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]{3,150}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Sorry, only alphanumerical characters are allowed and 3-150 character limit".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include 'header.php' ?>

<form action="index.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Username:*<input type="text" name="name" pattern="{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail:* <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>
Post:*<br>

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message'></textarea>
</div>

Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" > <br>
Your favorite website is: <input type="text" name="website">
Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <br>


<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p> Fields with * next to them are required </p>
<p><a href="index.php">Posting Wall</a></p>
<div id="time">
<?php 

$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'The time at which you are posting is:'. date('h:i Y-m-d') ."\n";
?>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Posting wall

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/post.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/heaader.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Daily Dorm News </h1>
<h2> You're best place for the latest dorm news from campus </h2>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php if ( isset($_GET['message']) and preg_match("/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/", $_GET['message']) ) {

    echo $_GET['message'];

} else {

    echo "The message is not valid! The message box was blank or you entered invalid symbols!\n";

}
?>

This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>
Your gender is:<?php echo $_GET["gender"]; ?><br>
Your favorite website is: <?php echo $_GET["website"]; ?><br>


</div>

<?php
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
* Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
*/

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);
$gender = strip_tags($_REQUEST['gender']);
$website = strip_tags($_REQUEST['website']);

$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
 // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  
$gender = strip_tags($_REQUEST['gender']);  
$website = strip_tags($_REQUEST['website']);  


 // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
 $post_fields = array();
 $post_fields['name'] = $name;
 $post_fields['email'] = $email;
 $post_fields['message'] = $message;
 $post_fields['date'] = $date;
  $post_fields['gender'] = $gender;
 $post_fields['website'] = $website;

 $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);

}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

?>


   <?php
   if(isset($name)) {
     echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
   }
   ?>
  <div id="logo"> Don't forget to tell all you're friends about Daily Dorm News! <br> The only dorm news website on campus!</div>

   <p id="received">Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
   <ul id="posts_list">
   <?php

   // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
   $counter = 1;

   foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
    $alreadyPosted = false;
     $name = $post['name'];
     $email = $post['email'];
     $message = $post['message'];
     $date = $post['date'];
      $gender = $post['gender'];
     $website = $post['website'];

     if ($counter % 2==1)
       $li_class = "float-left";
     else
       $li_class = "float-right";

     if ($name == $_GET['name']) {
        $alreadyPosted = true;
     }
        echo '<div class=post';
          if ($alreadyPosted) {
            echo ' id="highlight"';
          }
        echo '>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This event occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>Your a  '.$gender.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>You said your favorite website is  '.$website.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '</div>';
   }
   ?>

</ul>
</div>
<p id="submit"><a href="../index.php">Would you like to submit another post?</a></p>
<?php require 'footer.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the code for javascript that you tried?

Comment: I didnt use any java for doing the if else statements or the strip tags, just tried php, id rather it be in php also. I know its something like if(!empty(($date)) { echo "..."; } and the strip tags im not really sure about

Comment: Any idea? im not really sure, been trying for hours

Comment: try this to get the value of the datepicker: `$("input:text[name=date]").val();`. Or just add in the `required` attribute to that input.

Comment: whats wrong with this statement This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?> <?php if (empty(($date))) { echo "sorry..."; } ?><br>
 it says unexpected (

Comment: why do you enclose `$date` in two sets of `()`?

Comment: woops, now i changed it to This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?> <?php if (empty($date)) { echo "No date was entered!"; } ?><br>
however im still getting undefined index error, eventhough the input field is named $date in my form, you an see in the code in the OP Form.php so why does it give me the error if $date is real?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(empty(($date)) { 
    echo "sorry you did not enter a date"; 
}
```

**NOT**

```
if(!empty(($date)) { 
     echo "sorry you did not enter a date"; 
 }
```

The first expression will print "sorry you did not enter a date" if the date field is empty. The second expression will print that message if the date field is **not** empty.

You can try the code below. It will print 'This is an empty string'

```
<?php
$date = '';
if (empty($date)) {
    echo 'This is an empty string';
} 

if (!empty($date)) {
    echo 'The date is ' . $date;
}
```

Comment: Yes i want it, so if the field is empty, it prints sorry you did not enter a date. so the second one i want

Comment: No that is incorrect. !empty() means that the date is not empty (ie it has been filled out). You want to show an error with empty() is true. Please see the edit to my original answer. You can use the example code to see the difference between empty() and !empty().

Answer (score 0):

You can check through jquery in the submit function

```
var datepicker=$("#datepicker").val();
if(datepicker=='') { alert('Please enter date'); return false; }
```